# Sum a Range if All Cells in Range Are Numeric, Return Error if Not

Tags: vba, excel

NOTE: I am passing a range of cells to the function. Each cell in the range contains a formula that either returns a number or a string. The below code always returns an error. I think the code is returning an error because it is looking at the formula in the cell instead of the result of the formula. I want the code to test the result (either a number or a string) in each cell, not test the formula that produces the result. I thought the .value property would take care of this, but it apparently does not.

```
Function SmartSum(sumRange As Range) As Variant
'returns the sum of the the passed range IFF all elements in the range are numeric
'returns error if any of the elements in the range are not numeric, e.g., a text string

Dim ary As Variant
Dim i   As Long

ary = sumRange
SmartSum = 0

'sum all cells in range if they are numeric
'return an error if they are not
For i = LBound(ary, 1) To UBound(ary, 1)
    If IsNumeric(ary(i, 1)) Or ary(i, 1) = "" Then
        SmartSum = SmartSum + ary(i, 1)
    Else
        SmartSum = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Comment: `ary(i, 1).Value`-->`ary(i, 1)`

Comment: fyi you can also do this with a formula if that was your objective: using cntrl+shift+enter the formula as: `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1:A10)),SUM(A1:A10),#N/A)`

Comment: Thanks. My function still does not work because sometimes the formulas in the cells return "" and the function chokes on a cell value of "". See above modified code to show my failed solution to handle this. How can I change the code to correctly test for ""?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty string is not numeric, so when you try to add it SmartSum with the `+` operator, you get a type mismatch error. All errors in UDFs are reported as `#VALUE!` errors, so you can't tell if you're returning an error by design or if an error is actually happening.

Also, you're trying to return `xlErrValue`, but that's not what's really happening. When your code encounters a nonnumeric, it changes SmartSum to an error value. Then it tries to add the next value to the error value, which causes an error and the function returns `#VALUE!` (because of the internal error, not because of the `CVError()` function).

If you change `xlErrValue` to `xlErrNA`, your function would still return `#VALUE!`. You could rewrite your function like this if you want to return a different error.

```
Function SmartSum(sumRange As Range) As Variant
'returns the sum of the the passed range IFF all elements in the range are numeric
'returns error if any of the elements in the range are not numeric, e.g., a text string

Dim ary As Variant
Dim i   As Long
Dim vReturn As Variant

ary = sumRange
vReturn = 0

'sum all cells in range if they are numeric
'return an error if they are not
For i = LBound(ary, 1) To UBound(ary, 1)
    If IsNumeric(ary(i, 1)) Or Len(ary(i, 1)) = 0 Then
        vReturn = vReturn + ary(i, 1)
    Else
        vReturn = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

SmartSum = vReturn

End Function
```

Of course you don't want to do that, it's just illustrative of what's happening. With the above function, an empty string will cause a `#VALUE!` error (error *in* the function), but a nonnumeric will cause a `#N/A!` error (error *returned by* the function).

To account for the empty string, you can use the `Val()` function to force the value to be numeric. You already check for `IsNumeric()` so the only thing you'll be "forcing" is the empty string - everything else will happily convert to a number.

```
Function SmartSum(sumRange As Range) As Variant
'returns the sum of the the passed range IFF all elements in the range are numeric
'returns error if any of the elements in the range are not numeric, e.g., a text string

Dim ary As Variant
Dim i   As Long
Dim vReturn As Variant

ary = sumRange
vReturn = 0

'sum all cells in range if they are numeric
'return an error if they are not
For i = LBound(ary, 1) To UBound(ary, 1)
    If IsNumeric(ary(i, 1)) Or Len(ary(i, 1)) = 0 Then
        vReturn = vReturn + Val(ary(i, 1))
    Else
        vReturn = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

SmartSum = vReturn

End Function
```

Comment: Great answer. I suspected that having my function return the error would only add to my confusion, and your detailed explanation confirms this. Moreover, I tried every approach for handling the "" that I could think of, including Is Nothing, IsNull, IsEmpty, and vbNullString, all to no avail. I prefer "" because it makes my spreadsheets look cleaner than many zeroes filling my cells in the event of no result, but did not bargain on "" requiring such an elusive solution. The Val() function is new to me and now committed to memory. Thanks again.